# "Timeout trying to lock table" altering a table

Tags: h2

When I try to alter a table got the following response:

```
Timeout trying to lock table ; SQL statement:
ALTER TABLE FOO ADD COLUMN NAME VARCHAR(200) [50200-169] HYT00/50200 (Help)
```

H2 URL: `jdbc:h2:file:C:\h2\test;WRITE_DELAY=300;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_MODE=0;FILE_LOCK=SOCKET`

Run the following commands:

```
CREATE TABLE FOO (ID BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, CODE INTEGER NOT NULL)
@LOOP 6000 INSERT INTO FOO (CODE) VALUES (1)
ALTER TABLE FOO ADD COLUMN NAME VARCHAR(200) <== Here the problem happens
```

My H2 version is H2 1.3.169 (2012-09-09).

Comment: Try to include some more details; it's not very specific.

Answer (score 4):

[LOCK_MODE 0 means no locking.](http://h2database.com/html/grammar.html#set_lock_mode) It doesn't make sense to use this mode when using MVCC.

According to my test, it doesn't happen if you set LOCK_MODE to 1.

Answer (score 0):

It's looks like a bug... Interesting is that mentioned error doesn't show up when I use less records than mentioned on the question... For example, following sequence works:

1. Create the table: `CREATE TABLE FOO (ID BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, CODE INTEGER NOT NULL)`
2. Insert a bunch of records: `@LOOP 2000 INSERT INTO FOO (CODE) VALUES (1)`
3. Execute a alter table: `ALTER TABLE FOO ADD COLUMN NAME VARCHAR(200)`

On the other hand, changing it to insert 2001 records is enough to trigger `HYT00/50200` error.
The table itself doesn't need to be a complex one. Such error is reproduced with following table as well: `CREATE TABLE FOO (ID BIGINT NOT NULL, CODE INTEGER NOT NULL)`

I'll try get more details on that...

Few details about it:

- H2 error indicates a lock but all commands are entered through H2 Web Console this is the only connection used.
- A select on `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.LOCKS` returns no records.